# Selecting a css class with space xpath

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to select the following html snip

```
<span class="price-sales pdp-space-price" itemprop="price">39.90</span>
```

I tried:

```
$ps = $xpath->query("//*[@class='price-sales pdp-space-price']");
```

and

```
$ps = $xpath->query("//span[@class='price-sales pdp-space-price']");
```

NOTE: I need to select both class.

Comment: Try `//span[contains(@class, "price-sales") and contains(@class, "pdp-space-price")]` , but both your XPath in most cases should work...

Comment: @Andersson: it will execute only for span element. right?

Comment: I think 1st one tried should take care all elements which @class = 'price-sales pdp-space-price'.

Comment: @AmrendraKumar , yes. It will select `span` only. If OP wants to match all tags then `*` should be used